# How do you select a vertex group? (2.8 outliner error: Not yet implemented)

Tags: vertex-groups

I understand this feature is not implemented. Is there a workaround or another way of selecting a vertex group? All searches for an answer to this has only hinted that it's not possible to select via outliner, but one may be able to select a vertex group another way that is apparently so mysterious it is left unmentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex groups can be selected and modified from the "Object Data Properties" tab when you've selected an object.

[image: Object Data Properties]

Comment: You have to be in Edit Mode in order to see the Select button.